# Internet Access Controller in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I disable/enable an internet connection? Just want to disable internet connection only not `LAN`.

I tried this but it is not working

```
string[] connections = DisconnectWrapper.Connections();           
for (int i = 0; i < connections.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        DisconnectWrapper.CloseConnection(connections[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Smells bad to me..

Comment: @SonerGönül i want to schedule internet connection for specific intervals i am trying it with windows service but how to disable internet connection only that is the problem here...

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient description to help... what exactly happens (error messages/exceptions...) ?

Comment: There is no standard way to enable/disable internet connection since there are many ways how the internet connection is made... for example directly, via router, via modem etc. !

Comment: there is a Internet Access Controller software here i just want exactly like that you can check this link http://www.gearboxcomputers.com/products/

Comment: Nice of you to tell us you use Internet Access Controller. Why would anyone here know about that software (note to readers: this is not the Microsoft "IAC" product).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216).

Add `System.Management` to your referenced and try this code

```
 SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
            foreach (ManagementObject item in searchProcedure.Get())
            {
                if (((string)item["NetConnectionId"]) == "Local Network Connection")
                {
                    item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                }
            }
```

There is another article:[Disable/Enable Network Connections Programmatically](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2008/06/24/HOWTODisableEnableNetworkConnectionsProgrammaticallyUnderVista.aspx).

with `WMI` you can disable and enable all network connections.

**Edited:**

```
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter"))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Found adapter {0} :", obj["Caption"]);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Disabling adapter ...");
                object[] param = new object[0];
                obj.InvokeMethod("Disable",param);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Be aware Some of the adapter cannot be disabled.

Comment: it is not entering in item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null); connection is there

Comment: @Nighil:there is another way:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3eaedb67-0c34-4f7c-a360-8b079139fea2

Comment: This method is not implemented in any class in   if (((string)item["NetConnectionId"]) == "Local Area Connection")
                {
                    item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                }

Comment: still same error This method is not implemented in any class in the line obj.InvokeMethod("Disable", param);

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need by doing a shell call to netsh.

**Example:**

```
netsh interface set interface "Target Adapter Name" enabled
netsh interface set interface "Target Adapter Name" disabled
```

Netsh will block so if you wait for the process you spawn to exit, you'll know it's done.  It requires administrator privileges, so your process will also require it.  Netsh will set its exit code to 0 on success or 1 on failure, so you can check that for feedback if needed.